# Can I delete every other file than the compiled program?

Tags: visual-studio

When I build solution in Visual Studio (2022), it generates an EXE (or DLL if I chose a class library) just as expected, except it also generates some files, like PDB, and some CS files. I know what most of them do, but if I am making a software, which consists of multiple of these files, I wouldn't want or like some people looking at the application directory and find source files and/or source code and solutions. This makes me come up with a question: **Would deleting every single file except the compiled EXE or DLL impact their usability, or is there any other circumstance(s) to avoid creating these files, like SLN or PDB?**

Thanks in advance :)

<sub>I have not tried anything, because, I simply don't know how to prevent VS from creating these files, except compiled files.</sub>

Comment: I don't know how you configured your build, but finding `.cs` or `.sln` files in the build output directory seems rather strange ... Deployment is a totally different story. If you have some sort of deployment process (for instance create an installer package) you have to choose which files to include. you can safely ignore for instance PDB files in this process. They are for debugging purposes only ...

Comment: What folder are you looking at? Typically you would only need what is in bin/Release(/{platform} ) , or better, set up a deploy to some empty folder

Comment: First, in Visual Studio, I select "Create New Project", then I choose "Console App (.NET Framework)". Then I click Next, and I name my project "Whatever" (example). I save it in %USERPROFILE%\source\repos. Then, I write my code, and select Build Solution, or just the Play button right away to start without debugging. In Source Repos, I see a folder called "Whatever" (that's where's my project located, Whatever is my project's name as an example). In there, I see a SLN file, and another folder 'Whatever'. In bin/Debug or Debug/bin, I see a PDB file. I just want to generate EXE only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.pdb` files are outputs of your compilation. You can suppress them with:

```xml
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
```

The other files, like `.cs` and `.sln` are inputs to your project. Deleting them will mean you cannot build your program any more. I don't understand why you would want them to be deleted. If they're appearing in your output directory, check that you don't have "Copy local" (`CopyToOutputDirectory`) set on those items in your project.

Comment: The .cs files may be autogenerated by another build step. For example, XAML projects run the *.xaml files through the XAML compiler, which in turn produces *.cs files, and those *.cs files are compiled into the final project.